# WooCommerce sync with dropshipper through XML feed

Tags: xml, wordpress, woocommerce

How do I sync the quantity of my products on my WooCommerce page with the stock feed, that my dropshipper have provided me?

Thanks in advance.

Have a pleasant day :)

Comment: This is too broad and too much "Free work" for an SO question. Please show some effort: explain what you've tried, what you are expecting, where you are getting stuck. Ideally share some code samples. Or, consider hiring a developer to write the integration for you.

Comment: Hm... Haven't tried anything yet. Maybe someone knew a quick and good solution to use :)